# Monit fails to restart HHVM

Tags: php

Seems like monit has trouble to restart HHVM when it goes down, but judging by the error logs  I don't quite get why it can't restart it :

```
[UTC Dec 22 09:45:36] info     : 'hhvm' trying to restart
[UTC Dec 22 09:45:36] info     : 'hhvm' start: /etc/init.d/hhvm
[UTC Dec 22 09:45:36] error    : monit: Error reading pid from file '/var/run/hhvm/pid'
[UTC Dec 22 09:45:36] error    : monit: Error reading pid from file '/var/run/hhvm/pid'
[UTC Dec 22 09:45:37] error    : monit: Error reading pid from file '/var/run/hhvm/pid'
[UTC Dec 22 09:46:37] error    : 'hhvm' failed to start
[UTC Dec 22 09:46:42] error    : 'hhvm' process is not running
[UTC Dec 22 09:46:42] info     : 'hhvm' trying to restart
[UTC Dec 22 09:46:42] info     : 'hhvm' start: /etc/init.d/hhvm
[UTC Dec 22 09:47:42] error    : 'hhvm' failed to start
[UTC Dec 22 09:47:47] error    : 'hhvm' process is not running
[UTC Dec 22 09:47:47] info     : 'hhvm' trying to restart
[UTC Dec 22 09:47:47] info     : 'hhvm' start: /etc/init.d/hhvm
[UTC Dec 22 09:48:47] error    : 'hhvm' failed to start
[UTC Dec 22 09:48:52] error    : 'hhvm' process is not running
[UTC Dec 22 09:48:52] info     : 'hhvm' trying to restart
[UTC Dec 22 09:48:52] info     : 'hhvm' start: /etc/init.d/hhvm
[UTC Dec 22 09:49:52] error    : 'hhvm' failed to start
[UTC Dec 22 09:49:57] error    : 'hhvm' process is not running
[UTC Dec 22 09:49:57] info     : 'hhvm' trying to restart
```

It makes a call to the website on port 80 every 5 seconds and if it's down, it tries to restart it, but seems that it is not capable of it for some reason :

```
Config snippet :

check process hhvm with pidfile /var/run/hhvm/pid
    start program = "/etc/init.d/hhvm start" with timeout 60 seconds
    stop program = "/etc/init.d/hhvm stop"
    if failed host domain.com port 80 protocol http
        and request "/index.php"
    then restart
```

Any idea of why ? And if not, is there any other better way to check and restart HHVM if it goes down ?

This is the error log@ hhvm

```
Unable to start page server
Shutting down due to failure(s) to bind in HttpServer::runAndExitProcess
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
command failed: "lsof -t -i :9000 | xargs kill -9"
```

Comment: Is the process actually stopping or is it just crashing in some way? If you login to the server when you notice the site is down is the daemon still running?

Comment: Actually shortly after writing this I realized that the process is probably not dead, but it is just frozen and monin can't stop / restart it, I think I should stop the process via a kill better, but I am not sure yet how to make that work under monit

Comment: You could modify that start program to run both a ```/etc/init.d/hhvm stop && /etc/init.d/hhvm start``` the better solution would be to find out what the actual problem with hhvm is though.

Comment: the logs at hhvm are not showing anything else than what I have posted, is there any way to get more verbose ?

Comment: The HHVM Wiki page on Github shows configuration options for logging; https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/runtime-options

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was triggered because of a user permission issue on the directory where the pid is located. I am testing hhvm with a different user than the default www-data one but accidentally did start one with that user. This changed the permissions on that directory (/var/run/hhvm by default)

Fixing the permissions allowed me to get rid of the issue.